# In Emacs, how can I exclude '-' from the common delimiters?

Tags: emacs, elisp

When coding in elisp, I find that I'm stopping at hyphens when moving by words, and would prefer to ignore them.

What's the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`M-x modify-syntax-entry RET - RET w RET` should do it. Or if you prefer an elisp snippet that you can add into a hook, `(modify-syntax-entry ?- "w")`

The syntax table for a mode contains information on what constitutes various syntactic classes (e.g. words, spaces etc.). These are used to determine the operation of commands such as `forward-word` etc. Modifying it change the behaviour of these commands.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of changing Emacs' notion of words, it might be preferably to navigate by s-expressions (`C-M-f`, `C-M-b`) to skip whole identifiers. That way, you keep the convenience to be able to navigate by the partial words if you want to change an identifier.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This will work if I get used to walking over parentheses, which jump to the end of the expression. It's useful but will take some getting used to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use interactive regex search. Pressing just <kbd>C-M-s</kbd> <kbd>SPACE</kbd> should search for any whitespace (you might need to configure `search-whitespace-regexp`).

Comment: How does this address the problem of navigation?

Comment: Interactive search moves point, so it is kind of a navigation.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't answer his question which is to navigate by word. You can't use search to do that while typing practically.